# React, few function for event

Tags: reactjs, function, events

There is the script - during onMouseOver event the picture increases, during 
 onMouseOut - decreases. Also during onMouseOver occurs change of z-index (from 0 to 10), to increased picture was lied on top of the others. 
https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/k089ysxw/

But it is  wrong decision to set change of z-index during onMouseOver, because during onMouseOut z-index becomes 0. I see next deсision - to change z-index by the separate function, for example, hover, and add it function to both events.

But I make something wrong - Unexpected token

```
onMouseOver={(this, id)=>{this.increase.bind; this.hover.bind}}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/knrw67py/
How to sintactially correctly add two function to one event?

Comment: Just call the two functions in the arrow function you already have?

Comment: @Li357 in that case i have just 2 function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `this` as an argument name, it's a reserved word. You don't need to use it though, since arrow functions automatically bind `this` to the surrounding context. So taking it out would make your function work:

```
onMouseOver={(id)=>{this.increase.bind; this.hover.bind}}
```

**EDIT**

Looking at your fiddle, it seems that you're calling the methods incorrectly. This would fix it:

```
class Article extends React.Component {
  // Rest of your component ommitted for brevity

  render() {
    const TipStyle = {
      marginBottom: "10px"
    };

    return (
      <div style={TipStyle}>
        <h2 style={{ marginBottom: "1px" }}>{this.props.name}</h2>
        <div>
          {[1, 2, 3].map(id => {
            return (
              <img
                style={this.getImgStyle(id)}
                src={this.props[`img${id}`]}
                onMouseOver={() => {
                  this.increase(id);
                  this.hover(id);
                }}
                onMouseOut={() => {
                  this.increase(id);
                }}
              />
            );
          })}
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</pre>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Наташа edited answer, you should include your full component on the question for clarity

Comment: Now that is ok, even without chaging onMouseOut. If you want to see - https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/sw5o8qdv/ Thank you very much, that you helping me sort out, it is important theme.